# comparing columns in a dataframe for a desired output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Assume this is my input dataframe:

```
Name  Death1  Return1   Death2  Return2
 A     Yes     Yes       NaN      NaN
 B     No      No        Yes      Yes
 C     Yes     Yes       Yes      Yes
 D     NaN     NaN       NaN      NaN
```

I'm looking to count the number of times a character is dead and store it in a new column.

```
# My approach.
def clean_deaths(row):
    num_deaths = 0
    cols = ['Death1', 'Death2'] 
    for c in cols:
        death = row[c]
        if pd.isnull(death) or death == 'NO':
            continue
        elif death == 'YES':
            num_deaths += 1
    return num_deaths

df['Deaths'] = df.apply(clean_deaths, axis=1)
```

I was not satisfied with my approach. I'd like to see other ways to achieve this.

```
output: 
Name  Death1  Return1   Death2  Return2  Deaths
 A     Yes     Yes       NaN      NaN      1
 B     No      No        Yes      Yes      1
 C     Yes     Yes       Yes      Yes      2
 D     NaN     NaN       NaN      NaN      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need filter columns by names or [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), compare by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) (`==`) and last `sum` `True` values per rows:

```
df['Deaths'] = df[['Death1', 'Death2']].eq('Yes').sum(axis=1)
print (df)
  Name Death1 Return1 Death2 Return2  Deaths
0    A    Yes     Yes    NaN     NaN       1
1    B     No      No    Yes     Yes       1
2    C    Yes     Yes    Yes     Yes       2
3    D    NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN       0
```

---

```
df['Deaths'] = df.filter(like='Death').eq('Yes').sum(axis=1)
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df[['Death1', 'Death2']].eq('Yes'))
   Death1  Death2
0    True   False
1   False    True
2    True    True
3   False   False
```

Comment: If death1 had 'YES' in upper and death2 had 'yes' in lower caps then how can I solve it with the above approach?

Comment: @sai_636 - Use `df['Deaths'] = df.filter(like='Death').isin(['Yes', 'yes', 'YES']).sum(axis=1)`